# Laravel 8 JetStream Unable to locate Mix file: /css/app.css on npm run prod

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix, inertiajs

I have a Laravel 8 app running on Jetstream with Inertia Js and VueJs 3.

When I run: npm run prod

I receive this error:

```
Exception
Unable to locate Mix file: /css/app.css. (View: /var/www/html/mysite/resources/views/app.blade.php)
http://subdomain.mysite.com/
```

After changing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

and:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

to

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

It works well. But isn't this wrong? What is the advantage of using mix instead of asset?

I also tried using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(mix('css/app.css')) }}">` but it's still not working. I receive the same error saying that mix is unable to locate the file: `/css/app.css`

This is a simple Laravel app, without any customizations.

I tried to run `npm run prod` with the hope that the page size will be smaller, but I see the same page size as for `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` (17Mb).

Any advice for reducing the page size for a VueJs Laravel app?

**UPDATE**

webpack.mix.js content:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        tailwindcss('tailwind.config.js')
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

mix-manifest.json content:

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```

Comment: Can you please add `webpack.mix.js` and the `public/mix-manifest.json` to the question?

Comment: I added the requested details.

Comment: I assume the `mix-manifest.json` reflects a `npm run dev`. `npm run prod` should display hashed versions of the assets. When using hashed version you should use `{{ mix('js/app.js') }}` in your views. Does including the leading slash make a difference, so `mix('/js/app.js')`?

Comment: This suggestion didn't helped: "Does including the leading slash make a difference, so mix('/js/app.js')" . I still receive: Unable to locate Mix file: /css/app.css . I will use asset('css/app.css') and asset('js/app.js') for the moment since it works well.

Comment: I don't see the issue, but you didn't post your Tailwind and Webpack config files or your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following statements:

@vite(['resources/css/application.css', 'resources/js/application.js'])

For this:

Css: link rel="style sheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}"

JavasScript: src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer

In the app.blade.php and guest.blade files located in resources\views\layout